# Database/API for vegetable growing seasons?

Tags: vegetables

I'm looking for a database, (ideally an API!) that has information on the growing season of vegetables in various places. For example, what months can onions be harvested in Minneapolis? When are tomatoes in season in Atlanta?

Does such a thing exist?

Thanks!